# Automate - recover database using backup controfile

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, recovery

I am trying to automate a periodic clone of a database from one environment into another changing the database name.  I have done this many times manually by doing a begin/end backup on the source system, copying the storage shares and cloning them into the new location.  My hangup comes in automating the recovery piece.  After recreating the control file, I do the following command (generated from the backup of the control file to trace):

```
recover database using backup controfile
```

The problem is that this command has a prompt.  Because of the way I am doing the process, the archive logs needed are all present, so all that is necessary is to type AUTO.  Then after waiting for it to complete, do the `alter database open resetlogs`.

My question is, how can I automate this last piece?  I have a few ideas, but I'm not fond of any of them.  Hopefully, there is something obvious I am missing.

Update: 
I've tried using the `CONTINUE DEFAULT` syntax, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
SQL> RECOVER DATABASE UNTIL TIME '2015-10-20:13:54:16' USING BACKUP CONTROLFILE CONTINUE DEFAULT;
ORA-00274: illegal recovery option CONTINUE


SQL> RECOVER DATABASE UNTIL TIME '2015-10-20:13:54:16' CONTINUE DEFAULT USING BACKUP CONTROLFILE;
ORA-00274: illegal recovery option CONTINUE
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `AUTOMATIC`.

`RECOVER AUTOMATIC DATABASE UNTIL TIME '2015-10-20:13:54:16' USING BACKUP CONTROLFILE;`

`CONTINUE [DEFAULT]` is a different branch and can not be used together with clauses like `UNTIL` and `USING BACKUP CONTROLFILE`.

```
Control file created.

SQL> recover automatic database until change 473319 using backup controlfile;
Media recovery complete.
SQL> alter database open resetlogs;

Database altered.

SQL> select resetlogs_change# from v$database;

RESETLOGS_CHANGE#
-----------------
           473320
```

Comment: OK, I thought AUTOMATIC was the default, but if that works, it would be awesome.

Comment: It works, very obvious, and exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Add `CONTINUE DEFAULT`.

> Continues recovery using the redo log file generated automatically by
>   Oracle Database if no other logfile is specified. This is equivalent
>   to specifying AUTOMATIC, except that Oracle Database does not prompt
>   for a filename.

Documentation link [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve033.htm#SQPUG053).

Obviously other solutions would have involved scripting with `expect` or something similar.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.  Do I have the syntax wrong?  `SQL> RECOVER DATABASE UNTIL TIME '2015-10-20:13:54:16' USING BACKUP CONTROLFILE CONTINUE DEFAULT;
ORA-00274: illegal recovery option CONTINUE


SQL> RECOVER DATABASE UNTIL TIME '2015-10-20:13:54:16' CONTINUE DEFAULT USING BACKUP CONTROLFILE;
ORA-00274: illegal recovery option CONTINUE`